# Java and Flash Player do not work on Chromium

Tags: mac, google-chrome, adobe-flash, plugins

I've just installed the latest version of Chromium. But, neither Java nor Flash Player work.

How can this be fixed? As far as I can see, Chromium no longer supports PPAPI and NPPAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Google seems to think they know better than everyone else what people need to use online...

Here's the deal. They've deprecated those APIs, meaning if you want Java/Flash to work, you're out of luck.

*HOWEVER*, they haven't been removed yet, merely disabled. It'll get removed in a couple of major versions, but you can still force-enable them in the short term. This **WILL** stop working when Chrome 45 comes out in a few months. The only alternative then if you need Java/Flash will be to switch to a different browser.

In short:

For PPAPI plugins, go to `chrome://plugins`, scroll to the plugin, hit Details, and Under "Type: PPAPI," click Enable.

For NPAPI plugins, go to `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi`. There's an option there that says `Enable NPAPI`. Toggle that, and restart the browser.

I'd suggest getting used to Firefox or Safari in the meantime :(

Comment: yeah i know the option but it is not available for chromium. They have fully removed npapi and ppapi